# php count adding count results to a dynamic variable

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the results of a mysql query and want to add result to existing variable based on the results of the query.  The variable name is based on the id of the query result.  If the variable was not dynamic i could do:

```
 $count = 0;

 while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
   $count += $r['count'];
 }
```

is the below code the best way to do this when the variable is dynamic?

```
  while($r = $stmt->fetch()){
      $id = $r['id'];

      if (!isset($widgets[$id]['count'])){
         $widgets[$id]['count'] = $r['count'];
      }else{
         $widgets[$id]['count'] += $r['count'];
      }
  }
```

Comment: Are you asking for the best approach to approaching an issue, or you are actually having a problem with your code not working and you need help fixing the problematic code?

Comment: The above seems clunky to me.  Im curious if there is a better way.